# In GoodNotes 6, make a template with an overlay where I can write? Ex: Daily checklist, erasing checks at end of day

Tags: ipad

Is there something like layers in GoodNotes 6 app on iPad? Or perhaps a custom background under a notebook page?

I want to have a bottom layer where I occasionally add items such as daily to-do tasks. During the day I want that layer locked, so I cannot screw it up. As the day progresses I want to check off to-do tasks on an upper layer. At the end of the day, I will erase that upper layer to start fresh again tomorrow with a checklist of unchecked items.

Answer (score 1):

- Prepare a PDF with the template content you need, and load it into the Files app.
- Open Good Reader
- On the "Documents" screen (where all the notebooks are shown), select "Manage Notebook Templates" in Settings (icon top right)
- Tap on "edit" (to the right of the "Paper Templates" title)
- Scroll down, create a new group and then import the PDF you created in step 1

Comment: I was hoping to be able to edit the template conveniently within GoodNotes. Is a PDF the only way, even in version 6?

Comment: @BasilBourque JPG might work, I didn‘t try though. And there is always GoodNotes support via their website, especially for in-app functionality.